# Adding a Logon message to pages

Tags: session, authentication

I'm looking to create a log in feature every time users go to various members only pages, which returns them to the original page after logging in. I've seen various answers to this question but none of them seem to include a check feature followed by a return to the original page. At the moment the code I have created doesn't seem to recognize that I have logged in and keeps returning me to the log in form. Any answers will be greatly appreciated. I realize I am using deprecated code but that is the only version my host provider's servers recognize.

Here's the code I am putting at the top of each members page

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_SESSION['login'] != "yes" )
{
header("Location: main_login.php");
exit();
}
?>
```

This then opens the main_login.php page

```
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1"     bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Member Login </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="78">Username</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="mypassword" type="password" id="mypassword"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
```

On clicking the login button the following code in checklogin.php checks the entries

```
<?php

$host='.....'; // Host name 
$username='.....'; // Mysql username 
$password='........'; // Mysql password 
$db_name='....'; // Database name 
$tbl_name='......'; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"

session_start();
$_SESSION['myusername'];
$_SESSION['mypassword']; 
header("location:entry_form_european_languages.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

The last header location refers to the page I would like to return to, which seems to the repeat the process of opening up the login and check in files- as if to indicate that the return page doesn't recognize that the log in was successful.

I would need to add something that was relative to each page, but since I don't know where I am going wrong with the fixed page return, I can't move on to that stage of coding.

I did have an alternative header address which took it to the following page login_success.php which gave the impression that username entries had been accepted, but this doesn't allow me to return to the original page

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION[$myusername])){
header("Location:entry_form_european_languages.php");
}
?>

<?php

include '........';//Formatting for the page

?>

<html>
<body>
Login Successful
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've done some experimenting with this code and I realize it isn't working because of the use of the header function, but fixing it doesn't seem to be easy. Suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few extra things I needed to add to make the session details work, as follows. This code needs to go ahead of any other code on the page including any html code that relates to character formatting. Although I have coded it out the error reporting line is handy for indicating which line is not being read by the php server, should you have continued problems.

```
<?php
//error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
session_start();
ob_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['myusername'])){
    header('Location:main_login.php');
    }
    else if (isset($_SESSION['myusername'])){

    } 

    $myusername=$_SESSION['myusername'];

    $Page_Title ='Members Profile';

?>
```